# How would I be able to create this support beam?

Tags: modeling, objects, blender-internal-render-engine, edit-mode, geometry

[image]

If there are any informative YouTube tutorials which might help me achieve this please let me know, it looks simple to do but I cant figure out how to do it, thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you need it to be one object?

Comment: no not necessarily I just want to be able to create it.

Comment: This looks kind a Blender 101 thing. You will need only cubes scaled and rotated accordingly. Search for Blender modeling for beginners, there is a lot of tutorials.

Comment: I did it but is there any way of my showing you what I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a cube, press <kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd>

*(<kbd>S</kbd> for scale <kbd>Y</kbd> to lock the scale the Y-axis)*

Make it is long enough to be a steal beam, If you have done that you should have something like this. I modeled a steam beam for this don't mind it, this is meant to explain how you can achieve the effect.

[image: I modeled a steam beam for this don't mind it, this is meant to explain how you can achieve the effect.]

**Don't mind the shape, I you its about the idea**

After that duplicate the steel beam <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, move it up

Duplicate it 1 beam again and scale it smaller by doing <kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd> again and then rotate it 45° by pressing <kbd>R</kbd> and then type `45`

Place the metal beam in place , then duplicate the rotated metal beam, rotate it with 90°, place it next to the other rotated beam, and repeat

If you are having trouble placing or rotating the metal beams, press <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>, and then press <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>

After that you should be having something like this.

[image: 3]

If you wanted them to be one solid piece, select all metal beams and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

I hope this helped, if not feel free to ask for info.

**( I would show you more images but I cannot post more then 2 image links)**

Comment: thank you so much!!! but how did you make that shape of the beam?

Answer (score 0):

> thank you so much!!! but how did you make that shape of the beam? – Joshy

1.Start with a cube and resizing it to the correct width.

2. Go into edit mode and loop cut the cube 10 times

<kbd>cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> type 10 for 10 loopcuts

[image]

You should be having this now

[image: 6]

3. Leave 2 cuts open on both side and select the other 8
4. Move them down
5. Select the edges and bevel them

<kbd>cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Left down in the corner are settings to adjust the bevel

6. repeat the same progress on the other side

Hope this helped.

Comment: You should edit your previous answer, not add another one.

Comment: I was planning to, but I cannot add more pictures nor GIFs (I don't have a high enough reputation), since alot of these things are not easy to explain with just text.